# Data binding in collectionView does not work | MAUI

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, maui

I am trying to show some image only when an item from CollectionView is selected. To do this, I added the "IsSelected" field to the "Category" model and bind to it in CollectionView.ItemTemplate, but after changing the value of "IsSelected" to "true", the image does not appear

model:

```
public partial class Category : ObservableObject
{
    [JsonPropertyName("id")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;

    [JsonPropertyName("mobileImageUrl")]
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("isPublic")]
    public bool IsPublic { get; set; }

    [ObservableProperty]
    private bool isSelected;
}
```

collection view:

```
<CollectionView
    Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}"
    SelectionMode="Multiple"
    SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedCategories}"
    SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}">

    <CollectionView.Header>
        ...
    </CollectionView.Header>

    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="{OnIdiom Default=2}" />
    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Category">
            <AbsoluteLayout>
                            
                <Image 
                    Aspect="AspectFit" 
                    WidthRequest="165" 
                    Source="pzv.svg" 
                    Margin="0, 10" />
                            
                <Image
                    Aspect="AspectFit" 
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="130, 0, autoSize, autoSize"  
                    Source="selected_category.svg" 
                    IsVisible="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" >
                    <Image.Shadow>
                        <Shadow Brush="Black" Offset="0, 10" Opacity="0.1" Radius="15" />
                    </Image.Shadow>
                </Image>
                            
            </AbsoluteLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

</CollectionView>
```

viewmodel:

```
public partial class CatalogPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private readonly CategoryService categoryService;

    public ObservableCollection<Category> Categories { get; set; } = new();

    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableCollection<object> selectedCategories = new();


    public CatalogPageViewModel(CategoryService categoryService) 
    {
        this.categoryService = categoryService;

        InitAsync();
    }

    public async void InitAsync()
    {
        var categories = await categoryService.GetCategoriesAsync() ?? new();

        if (Categories?.Any() ?? false) Categories.Clear();

        foreach (var category in categories) Categories.Add(category);
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    public void OnSelectionChanged()
    {
        foreach (var selected in SelectedCategories)
        {
            if (selected is Category category)
            {
                foreach (var item in Categories.Where(x => x.Id == category.Id))
                {
                    item.IsSelected = true;
                }
            }
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Is IsSelected Observable?

Comment: @Jason, I just tried to make IsSelected an observable property, but it didn't give results

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what you’ve tried

Comment: are you sure your logic in `OnSelectionChanged` is working like you expect?

Comment: for me works if I remove the shadow. Also I think you want to have something like this in your OnCollectionChanged method:
foreach (var category in Categories)
{
     category.IsSelected = SelectedCategories.Contains(category); }

Comment: @pawelfelcyn, yes, it really works if you remove the shadow, thank you

Comment: It might be a bug with `autoSize`, when element initially has `isVisible="False"`. Try using numbers for layoutbounds width/height.